# How to pass variable to markdown? laravel mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I am using `MailMessage` to send a mail message to mailtrap, and I pass a variable `email`.

My problem it doesn't recognize the variable that I pass in the markdown. It returns an error below

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException: Undefined variable: email (View: /var/www/resources/views/ema...

Someone knows what is the proper way of passing and getting the variable from-to markdown?

---

Here is my code

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->greeting('hello')
    ->line('Innerline sample')
    ->action('Reset Button', 'http://localhost:3002/reset?sample=gibor213kg')
    ->line('sample')
    ->markdown('emails.reset')
    ->with('email', 'orange@gmail.com');
```

Here is my markdown look alike

```
@component('mail::layout', ['email' => $emaill])

//more codes here

{{ $email }}

//more codes here

@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got the solution, by using the `compact`, instead of an array. I changed this line below, and everything works normal.

```
->markdown('emails.reset', compact('email'))
```

credits to [@sibongisenimsomis](https://laracasts.com/@sibongisenimsomis) from laracasts

> Apparently passing variables to Markdown from Notification class works, differently. I used compact on my solution, after struggle for about an hour cause I was referring to another example which was using with, on a Mailable class.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/passe-some-variables-to-the-markdown-template-within-a-notification

Answer (score 2):

Pass the variable as a second parameter.

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->greeting('hello')
    ->line('Innerline sample')
    ->action('Reset Button', 'http://localhost:3002/reset?sample=gibor213kg')
    ->line('sample')
    ->markdown('emails.reset', [
        'email' => 'orange@gmail.com',
      ]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#markdown-mailables

Comment: same error happen. The way I get the variable in markdown is it right? I doubt